# Add div in Material expansion panel brokes component when collapsed

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-expansion-panel that contains some elements

I should apply a css style ( `break-inside: avoid-page`) the header + only the first so that the header + the first element avoids page break :

```
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
    <!-- #enddocregion multi -->
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <div class="break-page-inside">  <---- add this class from here
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    Personal data
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    Type your name and age
                    <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
                <input matInput>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>  <------------------------- to here
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="1">
        </mat-form-field>

    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <!-- #docregion disabled -->
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Day of the trip
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                Inform the date you wish to travel
                <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

The issue is when I collapse panels the first element is disappearing, when I expand them it's reappearing.

Here's a live [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p8m6pv?file=src%2Fexample%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.css)